# viewWillAppear method doesn't work

Tags: swift

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var family_name: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var given_name: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        family_name.center.x -= view.bounds.width
        given_name.center.x  -= view.bounds.width
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

viewWillAppear has no effect. When I run my app both text fields shouldn't be visible, but they are. I attached a photo with constraints; I think this can be the problem!

Comment: You can't change the frame (or centre) of a view when you are using AutoLayout. There are many questions like this on Stack Overflow that show various ways of getting around this. Now you know what the problem is (AutoLayout and moving views) you should be able to find the solution :D

Comment: Fogmeister is correct, you have to change constraints in your code to achieve this.

Comment: I have been trying without constraints, but the result is the same!

Comment: @Cristian the problem is that deleting the constraints does not mean that you're not using auto layout as the system adds constraints that are missing as a best guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `autolayout`, so frame change will not apply. your constraints will overwrite frame values after `viewWillAppear:`

Create `IBOutlet` for either right constraint or width constraint of your textFields.

Check below sample image to create IBOutlet of constraint.
[image]

In above image I have create outlet of height constraint.

To send textField outside of the view, suppose you have created right constraint.

```
//suppose initial value of right constraint is 20
constraintTextView1Right.constant = 20 + self.view.bounds.width;
self.view.layoutIfNeeded();//forcefully apply constraint with new values
```

After this, at some point in button click or in other event or after some delay, you can change value of constraintTextView1Right to 20,

```
constraintTextView1Right.constant = 20
self.view.layoutIfNeeded();//forcefully apply constraint with new values
```

your textFiled will come in the screen.

To animate the same you can write below code.

```
constraintTextView1Right.constant = 20
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) { () -> Void in
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded();//forcefully apply constraint with new values
        }
```